# How can I extract this List with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am making web service to connect order with worker who would make furnitures.

- Worker(name of Entity) can set up when they are available as String (ex: SUNDAY, MONDAY, ... SATURDAY).
- Order(name of Entity) can get visitDate when customer wants as LocalDate.

I'd like to make business logic to show customer page who are available for this order.
I was about to extract List about available Workers. But Idk how to extract because Some workers are available more than one day. Let's say A is available monday, tuesday, and friday, and if customer wants a worker to visit on 9th nov, How can i extract Lists?

Also, i'd like to use DTO, not Entity.

Comment: Maybe you should start by providing a db model, build your entities...

Comment: You can use `LocalDate#getDayOfWeek`, get day name and then lookup in the database for a worker who works on this day. If availability days are stored as string, you can use `LIKE` query with `%day%` matcher

Comment: Hi guys! I made enum type for data from Worker, and I understand getDayOfWeek! but what if a worker has multiple the available days, how can i make logics??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...when they are available as String" - I wouldn't do that but rather use the day of week field (i.e. 1-7) or an enum.

That being said there are many ways to approach this, like maintaining an actual list. Let's assume you've done this and your entities look like this:

```
@Entity
class Worker {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
    name="AVAILABILITY",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID")
  )
  @Column(name="WEEKDAY")
  private Set<DayOfWeek> availableAt;

  ...
}
```

Then you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT worker FROM Worker worker JOIN worker.availableAt av WHERE av = :selectedDayOfWeek
```

If you're using Hibernate (and if I remember correctly Spring Boot does so by default) you could also use [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-collection-expressions) and thus expressions like these:

```
SELECT worker FROM Worker worker WHERE :selectedDayOfWeek member of worker.availableAt

SELECT worker FROM Worker worker WHERE :selectedDayOfWeek in elements(worker.availableAt)

SELECT worker FROM Worker worker WHERE :selectedDayOfWeek = some  elements(worker.availableAt)
```

Disclaimer: I haven't used JPA and Hibernate directly in a while so there may be some errors in the code above. The approach should still be valid tough.